# Visitor is tracked twice if using Piwik JS and PHP API on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, matomo

I have the problem that I have to use the JS and PHP API of Piwik on my site at the same time. 
Which is in general no problem but each visitor is tracked twice. 
I'm already pushing the IP with my PHP code but that's obviously not enough. 
Now I thought I could set a unique VisitorID but it seems that this is not possible in the JS API.

What can I do to get tracked each visitor just once?

Thanks in advance, 
Martin

Comment: Seeing that it gives you double the users, try cutting it in half?

Comment: no, don't get me wrong. Each action of the visitor is just tracked once but the actions which are tracked with php API are accounted to a different visitor than the actions from JS even if it is the same one (I can see it on user IP)